# Proving $ \lim_{x \to \infty } \frac{5x^{2}+1}{7x^{2}-3} = \frac{5}{7} $ using the limit definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I have problem particularly with this:

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty } \frac{5x^{2}+1}{7x^{2}-3} = \frac{5}{7} $$

I understand the logic of such proofs when it comes to simple functions as $f(x) = x + 4$ or $f(x) = \frac 1x$, however, I struggle with solving something like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Highlights:

$$\left|\frac{5x^2+1}{7x^2-3}-\frac57\right|=\frac{22}{7(7x^2-3)}\;\;(**)$$

You can take out the absolute value as $\;x\to\infty\;$ and thus you can assume $\;x>\sqrt\frac37\;$ . Also, for $\;x\;$ big enough as to fulfill $\;7x^2-3>22\;$ , say, you get above that

$$(**)<\frac17$$

Now get into the game $\;\epsilon,\,\delta\;$ and prove what you want.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand the logic of such proofs when it comes to simple functions as [...] f(x) = 1/x

Here is one way to reduce it to the case you know.

- First, write it as $\,f(x)=\frac{5x^{2}+1}{7x^{2}-3}=\frac{5}{7}\cdot\frac{x^2+1/5}{x^2-3/7}=\frac{5}{7}\cdot\left(1+\frac{22/35}{x^2-3/7}\right)=\frac{5}{7} \cdot \left(1+g(x)\right)\,$
- $g(x)$ only depends on $y=x^2$ so look at $g(x)=h(y)=\frac{22}{35}\cdot\frac{1}{y - 3/7}$
- Let $z=y-3/7$, then $h(y)=k(z)=\frac{22}{35}\cdot\frac{1}{z}$

Now, you know that $\lim_{z \to \infty} k(z) = 0\,$ from what you wrote. It follows from there that $\lim_{y \to \infty} h(y) = 0\,$, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = 0\,$, and finally $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \frac{5}{7}\,$.

Comment: @dx The OP asked for a proof *using the definition of limit* ...

Comment: @DonAntonio The OP also mentioned *what they know* (+1 for that), and it may be useful for them to point out how that relates to the question they asked. That said, and quoting from another recent comment of mine: "*answers on MSE are meant to help (a) the OP, but also (b) others who may happen to research the same question later on and come upon this topic, quite possibly in different contexts with different backgrounds. Because of (b) it is advisable that you not dismiss offhand what is otherwise a good answer*".